got an error while converting .py to .exe
I have a school project that is in .py but I want it to be in .exe along with all of its dependencies, it is a gui based keylogger, when I type pyinstaller -F pyinstaller -F main.py and  I get that:
pyinstaller -F main.py
448 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.4.0, contrib hooks: 2024.1
449 INFO: Python: 3.12.1
476 INFO: Platform: Windows-11-10.0.22631-SP0
477 INFO: wrote D:\012IP\main.spec
486 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\012IP']
965 INFO: checking Analysis
965 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
965 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
967 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
983 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2917 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4663 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5820 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6269 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6452 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6453 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
6460 INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\Users\asrar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.dll
6460 INFO: Analyzing D:\012IP\main.py
6628 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pynput.py' from 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
7209 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
7522 INFO: Processing module hooks...
7528 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7529 INFO: checking Tree
7530 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
7530 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
7601 INFO: checking Tree
7601 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
7601 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
7610 INFO: checking Tree
7610 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
7611 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
7624 INFO: Performing binary vs. data reclassification (925 entries)
7806 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
7825 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
7827 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
7830 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
7860 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
8086 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): []
8086 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): []
8270 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8271 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8271 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8272 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8272 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8273 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8273 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8274 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8274 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8275 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8275 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8276 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8276 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
8277 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
8277 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
8277 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
8278 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
8278 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
8279 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
8279 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
8280 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_hashlib.pyd'.
8280 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_hashlib.pyd'.
8281 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_lzma.pyd'.
8281 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_lzma.pyd'.
8281 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_bz2.pyd'.
8282 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_bz2.pyd'.
8282 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_bz2.pyd'.
8283 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\unicodedata.pyd'.
8283 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\unicodedata.pyd'.
8284 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\unicodedata.pyd'.
8284 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\select.pyd'.
8285 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_socket.pyd'.
8285 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_socket.pyd'.
8286 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_socket.pyd'.
8287 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_ctypes.pyd'.
8287 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_ctypes.pyd'.
8288 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_ctypes.pyd'.
8288 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_queue.pyd'.
8289 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_tkinter.pyd'.
8289 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_tkinter.pyd'.
8289 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_tkinter.pyd'.
8289 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
8290 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
8290 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
8290 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
8292 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
8292 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8292 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8292 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8293 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8293 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8293 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8295 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8295 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8295 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
8295 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libffi-8.dll'.
8296 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8296 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8296 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8297 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8297 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8298 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8298 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8298 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8299 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
8299 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
8300 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
8300 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
8301 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
8301 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
8303 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
8303 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
8304 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\asrar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
8386 INFO: Warnings written to D:\012IP\build\main\warn-main.txt
8409 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\012IP\build\main\xref-main.html
8457 INFO: checking PYZ
8457 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
8457 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\012IP\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
8844 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\012IP\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
8874 INFO: checking PKG
8875 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
8875 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg
11823 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg completed successfully.
11846 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\asrar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\run.exe
11847 INFO: checking EXE
11847 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
11847 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
11848 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to D:\012IP\dist\main.exe
11924 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
11995 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
11996 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
12067 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
12078 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
16119 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

how do i fix this issue
the following is the content for main.py
import logging
import os
import subprocess
import threading
import webbrowser
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import *

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

# Determine the base directory of the script
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

class KeyloggerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(KeyloggerThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        logging.basicConfig(filename=BASE_DIR / "keyboarddata.txt", level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
        with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

def start_keylogger_thread():
    global keylogger_thread
    keylogger_thread = KeyloggerThread()
    keylogger_thread.start()
    button_4.config(state="disabled")  # Disable start button after starting

def stop_keylogger():
    keylogger_thread.stop()
    button_4.config(state="normal")  # Enable start button after stopping
    window.withdraw()  # Hide the tkinter window

    # Check if the window should be shown again or if the program should exit
    def check_window_state():
        if not keylogger_thread.is_alive():  # If keylogger thread has stopped
            window.destroy()  # Destroy the tkinter window
        else:
            window.after(1000, check_window_state)  # Check again after 1 second

    window.after(1000, check_window_state)  # Start checking window state

def open_keyboard_data():
    subprocess.run(["notepad.exe", str(BASE_DIR / "keyboarddata.txt")])

def kill_keylogger():
    os._exit(0)

def check_agreement():
    agreement_text = entry_1.get()
    if "i agree" in agreement_text.lower():
        button_2.config(state="normal")
        button_3.config(state="normal")
        button_4.config(state="normal")
        button_5.config(state="normal")
        button_6.config(state="normal")
    else:
        button_2.config(state="disabled")
        button_3.config(state="disabled")
        button_4.config(state="disabled")
        button_5.config(state="disabled")
        button_6.config(state="disabled")

def open_youtube_link():
    webbrowser.open("https://youtu.be/zGiNGnX5dYg?si=kd02XcV0kysm1lZj&t=32")

window = Tk()
window.title('Keylogger')

# Load background image using relative path
bg_image = PhotoImage(file=str(BASE_DIR / "assets" / "frame0" / "bg.png"))
bg_width = bg_image.width()
bg_height = bg_image.height()

window.geometry(f"{bg_width}x{bg_height}")
window.configure(bg="#000000")

bg_canvas = Canvas(window, bg="#000000", height=bg_height, width=bg_width, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge")
bg_canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
bg_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=bg_image)

entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(file=str(BASE_DIR / "assets" / "frame0" / "entry_1.png"))
entry_bg_1 = bg_canvas.create_image(135.5, 324.0, image=entry_image_1)

entry_1 = Entry(bg_canvas, bd=0, bg="#DAE6F4", fg="#000716", highlightthickness=0)
entry_1.place(x=65.0, y=308.0, width=141.0, height=30.0)

button_image_1 = PhotoImage(file=str(BASE_DIR / "assets" / "frame0" / "button_1.png"))
button_1 = Button(bg_canvas, image=button_image_1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=check_agreement, relief="flat")
button_1.place(x=65.0, y=350.0, width=93.88436889648438, height=32.0)

button_image_2 = PhotoImage(file=str(BASE_DIR / "assets" / "frame0" / "button_2.png"))
button_2 = Button(bg_canvas, image=button_image_2, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=stop_keylogger, relief="flat", state="disabled")
button_2.place(x=672.0, y=280.0, width=91.0, height=44.0)

button_image_3 = PhotoImage(file=str(BASE_DIR / "assets" / "frame0" / "button_3.png"))
button_3 = Button(bg_canvas, image=button_image_3, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=open_youtube_link, relief="flat", state="disabled")
button_3.place(x=493.0, y=230.0, width=318.0, height=30.0)

button_image_4 = PhotoImage(file=str(BASE_DIR / "assets" / "frame0" / "button_4.png"))
button_4 = Button(bg_canvas, image=button_image_4, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=start_keylogger_thread, relief="flat", state="disabled")
button_4.place(x=535.0, y=280.0, width=91.0, height=44.0)

button_image_5 = PhotoImage(file=str(BASE_DIR / "assets" / "frame0" / "button_5.png"))
button_5 = Button(bg_canvas, image=button_image_5, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=open_keyboard_data, relief="flat", state="disabled")
button_5.place(x=553.0, y=333.0, width=197.0, height=44.0)

button_image_6 = PhotoImage(file=str(BASE_DIR / "assets" / "frame0" / "button_6.png"))
button_6 = Button(bg_canvas, image=button_image_6, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=kill_keylogger, relief="flat", state="disabled")
button_6.place(x=593.0, y=400.0, width=120.0, height=30.0)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()



can u try pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=module_name main.py

Note that warnings and errors are two different things. Make sure you're showing us an actual error.

(to lay this out, the log says it is successfully building an exe; if that exe doesn't actually work when you run it, you need to show us that as part of the question).

Are you on the latest version of pyinstaller? Do pip install --upgrade pyinstaller in CMD then try again

An answer should be provably correct; for speculation, use comments when you have enough reputation to add them.
